# How can I implement a C# server that receives JSON data and how to POST it?

Tags: c#, json, post, cordova, webserver

I have a phonegap iOS app which has a form that, when submitted, it should post some json data to a server and get a response. I have to use C# on the server side and listen somehow when the json is posted from the form in the phonegap app, do some stuff with the data and then respond to the phonegap app. How can I implement the c# server and how should I post the data from my html form? I am experienced in c# desktop applications, but I am really new to everything related to web stuff. The ios app is running in an iphone simulator on a mac in my local network. I have searched for resources but I haven't been able to do this and have been trying for a while. I think I don't need the whole code, just advice on how to do it and what to use.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Look up some tutorials on MVC Web API.  I found it easy to handle json.

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview) is exactly what you need. It's a framework for creating web APIs that receive and respond to requests coming through the web, which of course includes JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems like what I need. Just a little question, I tried using a tcp listener and when I went into the server's ip and port, it worked fine, but when I tried posting from my form to that url (http://192.168.10.5:8080) nothing happened. Is there a special way I should post the data or will the asp.net web api take care of this too?

Comment: From what I can tell that's mostly a server issue not an implementation issue. Maybe your server wasn't setup correctly, maybe you had a firewall up. Using ASP.NET WebApi will mean using IIS which *should* make configuring that sort of thing easier.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC and/or ASP.Net WebAPI are perfect for this.  Check out the resources at http://asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

The MS Web API won't help with writing a server.

You don't need to write your own server, but you can if you so choose.

1. Setup and run IIS.
2. Make a simple ASP.NET Web Forms application
3. Handle the Page_Load event
4. Read the value of your json from the posted data using `Request.Form["json"];` or whatever you called your posted fields.
5. `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`  will help to deserialize your json.  Just make a class for your types. You'll have add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.
6. Publish your application to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).  It's highly testable, easy to host, and in my experience magnitudes faster than any of the MS web service platforms.  Plus, as you don't state what platform your server is, ServiceStack can be hosted on both Windows and Linux systems.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mono
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting